# scrollTop value doesn't correlate to actual pixels

Tags: javascript

I'm having an issue with the `scrollTop` property in JavaScript and was hoping someone could help. According to MDN, the value corresponds to a pixel offset, which makes sense. What I'm having trouble with is the fact that it doesn't seem to be that simple. Here's a Codepen example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGJZMV

I want to create a shrinking header effect in which the header shrinks up to a certain point upon scroll and then stops. Sounds simple enough (and should be). I'm listening to the 'scroll' event on my scrollable element and subtracting the value from the maximum header height, with some conditionals ensuring it stays between my desired amounts. I'm not using any kind of scalar multiplier on my difference function so, in my mind, there should be no parallax scrolling effect happening between the scrollable area and the header (though in my example, there clearly is). Any ideas?

EDIT:
To better clarify the problem, I want the header to shrink at the same rate the text scrolls so that the text does not go behind the header until the header is at its minimum height. The way it is now, the vertical translation of the content box effectively causes the text to move twice as fast as its scrollTop value because it's both scrolling and translating.

Comment: Downvote with no reason? Thanks :) If it's the absence of code, I linked to it. If it's not that, you should at least provide an explanation.

Comment: I've realized why it's happening but am not sure on how to fix it. The content box is repositioning while the header shrinks, so in a sense, the content is scrolling twice as fast. I need to find a way to not really scroll until the header has shrunk to where I want and then let it scroll normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After realizing what the real issue was (the text container translating vertically while also scrolling), I was able to resolve it by padding the top of the content container by the scroll amount, thereby pushing the text down to compensate for the container's vertical movement. This updated pen shows the result, in case anyone is interested:

http://codepen.io/sunny-mittal/pen/LNjgEK

The relevant changes to the previous code are surrounded with asterisks:

```
header.on 'scrolling' (_, howmuch) ->
  if howmuch is 0
    header.css 'height' 150
    **content.css 'padding-top' 0**
  else if howmuch >= 50
    header.css 'height' 100
    **content.css 'padding-top' 50**
  else
    header.css 'height' 150 - howmuch
    **content.css 'padding-top' howmuch**
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "parallax scrolling effect", you mean that the header shrinks slower than the content scrolls, then it is because of your CSS. In your CSS, you have a line that says `transition all 0.3s ease` for your `header`. This means that all properties will not have changes apply immediately, but will "animate" for 0.3s with an easing. Every time you change `header` height, it would take 0.3s, regardless of whatever is happening in the rest of the world.

If you remove that line, `header` should shrink at the same rate as your `content`.

Comment: I added that for effect but it's not the reason. After all, if you scroll a little and wait, the animation will complete, yet it still results in the text passing below the header well before the header has shrunk to its minimum. It must be something simple I'm missing, so I'll keep looking. Thanks for the response, though!

Comment: I think you should state the problem more clearly in your question. From the words you wrote, it's not entirely clear what is the problem.